# Add a row count to the order sales view items table - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, sales-order, sales-order-view

We want to add a row count in the order sales view items table.

So that we can see and define the rows, to make it more easy to manage the order.
We already tried `$block->getItem()->getId()` for the class `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn` but the problem is that this number is not specific for this order but the Id of all orders.

How can we achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

Lets start by creating a module `Vendor_RowCounter`, with the required files, and shared files for both solutions:

1. Add `registration.php`:

```php
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_RowCounter',
    __DIR__
);
```

2. Add `etc/module.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_RowCounter"/>
</config>
```

3. Create a block file, `Block/Adminhtml/Items/Column/Row.php`:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\RowCounter\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column;

use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn;

class Row extends DefaultColumn
{

    /** @var int */
    private int $row = 1;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRow(): int
    {
        return $this->row++;
    }
}
```

4. Create template file, `view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/row.phtml`:

```
<?php
use Vendor\RowCounter\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Row;
/** @var Row $block */
?>

<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>_row">
        <?= $block->getRow(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

#### Solution #1 (By adding a column via `sales_order_view.xml`):

1. Create `view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="row" xsi:type="string" translate="true">#</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Vendor\RowCounter\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Row" name="column_row" template="Vendor_RowCounter::items/column/row.phtml" group="column"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="row" xsi:type="string" translate="true">col-row</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The drawback with this approach is you won't have control over the order of columns and a new column will be added at the end:
[image: Solution#1]

#### Solution #2 (By adding a column via plugins):

To take more control over the column order, we can add column via plugin instead of `sales_order_view.xml`.

1. Add `view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <block class="Vendor\RowCounter\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Row" name="column_row" template="Vendor_RowCounter::items/column/row.phtml" group="column"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. Add `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` for the plugins:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items">
        <plugin name="Vendor_RowCounter::OrderViewItems" type="Vendor\RowCounter\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer">
        <plugin name="Vendor_RowCounter::OrderViewItemsDefaultRenderer" type="Vendor\RowCounter\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

3. Add first plugin class, `Plugin/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Items.php`

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\RowCounter\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items as BaseItems;

class Items
{

    /**
     * @param BaseItems $subject
     * @param array $result
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetColumns(
        BaseItems $subject,
        array $result
    ): array {
        return [
            'row' => __('#'),
            ...$result,
        ];
    }
}
```

4. Add the other plugin, `Plugin/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Items/Renderer/DefaultRenderer.php`

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\RowCounter\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer;

use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer as BaseDefaultRenderer;

class DefaultRenderer
{

    /**
     * @param BaseDefaultRenderer $subject
     * @param array $result
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetColumns(
        BaseDefaultRenderer $subject,
        array $result
    ): array {
        return [
            'row' => 'col-row',
            ...$result,
        ];
    }
}
```

Result of Solution #2:
[image: Solution#2]